# Can you save the split value in the split function?

Tags: python

I want to create a number operator number calculator with the ".split()" function, so I am taking the string, it's an input but how would I know what operator he typed? is there a way to save the operator so to do something like that:

```
well = raw_input("Enter num")
checkopirator = well.split("*+-")
if(checkopirator == '*'):
  print checkopirator[0] * checkopirator[1]
if (checkopirator == '+'):
  print checkopirator[0] + checkopirator[1]
if (checkopirator == '-'):
  print checkopirator[0] - checkopirator[1]
```

Comment: *I know how .split works. I just tried to make you guys understand what I want exactly* (your comment on an answer). In that case you may have an [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 0):

You can use negated regex expression to match all characters that are not digits or letters

**Example:**

```
import re

string1 = "2+2=5"
string2 = "25-16=9"

results1 = re.findall(r"[^A-Za-z0-9]", string1)
results2 = re.findall(r"[^A-Za-z0-9]", string2)

print(results1)
print(results2)
```

**Output:**

```
['+', '=']
['-', '=']
```

Answer (score -1):

That's not how `split()` works... In fact, in your example it'll *only* split the input if the whole string `"*+-"` is present! This is closer to what you intended - assuming integers are used as input, and don't forget that you need to convert the input to numbers:

```
import re

well = raw_input("Enter num: ")
checkoperator = re.split(r'[*+-]', well)

if '+' in well:
    print(int(checkoperator[0]) + int(checkoperator[1]))
elif '-' in well:
    print(int(checkoperator[0]) - int(checkoperator[1]))
elif '*' in well:
    print(int(checkoperator[0]) * int(checkoperator[1]))
```

For example:

```
Enter num: 6 * 7
42
```

Comment: I know how .split works. I just tried to make you guys understand what I want exactly

Answer (score -1):

You can use `re.split` to split based on any occurrence of `+-*`

```
import re
n1, operator, n2 = re.split(r'([*+-])', well)
if operator == '*':
    print int(n1) * int(n2)
...
...
```

Comment: This isn't what OP was asking for

Comment: @G.Anderson OP says he wanted to get number operator number using something like split. And I believe thats exactly what I have provided. Care to explain why you think OP was asking for something else?